# How to calculate tax in for configurable product in magento1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, tax

I  am working on removing tax in certain condition of the product.I had overridden getFinalPrice() for this but unfortunately it is not working in case of configurable products.
Please help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case I have overridden the configurable file to get the getprice() fucnction working on configurable products.

Answer (score 1):

If you have rewrite Price class then it will not work for configurable product as configurable product has it's own getFinalPrice method in Price Class..

Instead try to use observer for catalog_product_get_final_price event and update price. It should update price for all product types.